# Geolocation Altitude problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, networking, geolocation

I am getting an incorrect location when I attempt to locate myself using the geolocation services. I'm on the 13th floor so I thought that might be an issue. I went outside for a minute and tested it at ground level, and it worked.

So, now I'm trying to figure out a way to correct for altitude. I've checked through all the questions and everything and I found nothing that is close enough that could help. I tried the highAccuracy method, but nothing came of it.

Here's my code:

```
var you;
var directions;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


var pj = {
    address: "57575 190th Street, Pacific Junction, IA 51561",
    latitude: 41.018899,
    longitude: -95.822685
};
var tifton = {
    address: "267 Southwell Blvd, Tifton, GA 31794",
    latitude: 31.417032,
    longitude: -83.498785
};
var nlv = {
    address: "4020 East Lone Mountain Road #105, North Las Vegas, NV 89030",
    latitude: 36.228928,
    longitude: -115.112426
};

//get the map that was clicked
$('.map').click(function(){
    //determine which map it was that was clicked
    var map = $(this).data('map');

    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction, {'enableHighAccuracy':true,'timeout':10000,'maximumAge':0});
    }
    function successFunction(position){
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        switch(map){
            case 'pj':
                codeLatLng(lat, lng, pj['address']);
                break;
            case 'tifton':
                codeLatLng(lat, lng, tifton['address']);
                break;
            case 'nlv':
                codeLatLng(lat, lng, nlv['address']);
                break;
        }
    }
    function errorFunction(){
        alert('Oops! It looks like the Geocoder service is down at the moment. Please try again later!');
    }
});

function codeLatLng(lat, lng, loc){
    var spot = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({"location": spot}, function(results, status){
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){        
            if(results[1]){
                you = results[0].formatted_address;
                alert(you);
                var request = {
                    origin: you,
                    destination: loc,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                };

                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
                    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                        $('.modal-title').html("Directions to "+response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['end_address']);
                        $('.modal-body').append('<p class="text-primary"><b>Estimated Travel Time: </b>'+response["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["text"]+'</p>');
                        $('.modal-body').append('<p class="text-primary"><b>Estimated Distance: </b>'+response["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"]+'</p>');

                        for(var i = 0; i < response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'].length; i++){
                            $('.modal-body').append('<p><span class="text-info">Step '+(i+1)+':</span> '+ response["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["steps"][i]["instructions"] + '</p>');
                        }
                        $('#map-directions').modal('show');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                alert("No results found");
            }
        }else{
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });     
}
```

EDIT: Here is a summary of the different things that have have happened,

```
- PHONE: 
    - On wi-fi on the 13th floor of my building: Off by 2 city blocks
    - On the cell network in my building: off by two miles and in the wrong state
    - On the cell network outside: accurate anywhere
- PC: 
    - On wi-fi on the 13th floors: Accurate to the point
    - On the LAN network: off my 1.5 miles southeast
```

So with that being said, how to I make it accurate all the way around?

How can I allocate for the altitude change?

Comment: I don't think altitude has anything to do with this. When you were on the 13th floor, were you on a LAN (WiFi or wired) or mobile phone network? Same questions for when you were outside. Also, does the device you're using have a GPS built into it?

Comment: Well here's an update for you, then we can go through this issue together if you want, because I would like to really solve it. I am on a LAN network here on the 13th floor on my computer. I am also on wifi on my phone. I was on the phone network while outside of my building at ground level. I have edited above to show you the summary of what has happened.

Comment: When you're outside with the phone, you're using GPS. When you're indoors, connected to a (non-mobile) network, you're relying upon a database that maps IP addresses to physical location. These databases are rarely "pinpoint" accurate, except in the case of public WiFi hotspots where someone has logged the coordinates of that hotspot in that database. If your phone can get a reliable GPS signal inside your building, it should be using that as its primary source; what happens if you turn off WiFi on the phone when you're indoors?

Comment: The only one I can't explain is the result of the last test; that should yield results similar to the phone on WiFi or PC on the LAN. Is that WiFi access point public, and is it connected to the same LAN (reaches the public internet via the same external IP)?

Comment: Sorry I got the phone backwards up top there. When the phone is on wifi it is closer to the bulding, but not 100% accurate It's off about 2 city blocks. When it's on the network it throws me across the river to the other state.

Comment: Then your phone results seem pretty logical to me. The PC on Wifi is the only mystery right now.

Comment: Agreed, the phone never fails, and I'm not worried about that so much because 8/10 times people using google maps are not on a wifi network. The PC deal is really baffling me though, i'm researching the hell out of it, and it sucks because it's taken up the bulk of my 8 hour day today :/

Comment: For any device not equipped with GPS, you're not going to get a good, reliable location. What I'm saying above is that I'm surprised you're getting a 100% accurate reading *at all* on the PC.

Comment: oh okay I see that now, I'm terrible with reading comprehension some days. Well how is that possible then since my phone is equipped with GPS and it gets two incorrect responses from my location regardless.

Comment: Inside the building it's probably getting a weak, bad or multi-pathed GPS signal. Sometimes it'll work, sometimes it won't.

Comment: ah okay, I've got it, well I wish you would have used one of these as an answer and I would have accepted it, or a vote up, so that maybe I could get some more feedback from other users and see what they think. I still think there is something to be said for the LAN issue.